# Scroll List page with fixed button at the bottom IONIC

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I would like to display ion-list in a page that has fixed submit button at the bottom of the page. If I place a submit button at the bottom, it scrolls down below the list. I want to fix the button at the bottom and list should occupy only 70% of the screen. List has to scroll within that 70% height.

Please let me know how to make bottom submit button fixed and with fixed height for ion-list.

Thanks,

Comment: Use ion-footer and make transparent background of ion-footer then add button inside ion-footer for height you can adjust it by css.

Answer (score 2):

To set a fixed button at the bottom you can use `<ion-footer>` which will set your content always at the footer part of the screen.

```
<ion-header> // For setting navigation bar or toolbar in header part
<ion-footer> // For setting bottom bar with non scrollable content
```

**Sample code:**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle><ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon></button>
    <ion-title>List</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemTapped($event, item)">
      <ion-icon [name]="item.icon" item-start></ion-icon>
      {{ item.title }}
      <div class="item-note" item-end>{{ item.note }}</div>
    </button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <div><button ion-item>Submit</button></div>
</ion-footer>
```

in the above code, I placed footer outside  so it will stay always at footer position after ion-content.

Ref Link :

[ion-header](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Header/)

[ion-footer](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Footer/)

And your list will scroll without the footer button.